# Script to change state of wireless card

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, iproute

Seeing as the hotkey on my laptop doesn't change the state of my wireless card, I wanted to create a short script that would do so and then map it to that key.

My research tells me that `.sh` files are bash script files that can be 'executed' (in a way), so I set about creating a `.sh` file with the following script;

```
#!/bin/bash

if
    ( ip link set wlan0 "up" );
then
    sudo ip link set wlan0 down
else
    sudo ip link set wlan0 up
fi
```

I'm running the script using the `./` command and it works in one direction but not vice versa;

Up → down

** **EDIT** **

I forgot to mention that my build is Kali Linux (Debian) and I'm using iproute2

Answer (score 1):

If Kali is using NetworkManager, you should have nmcli command available, and then merely set wifi radio on/off using

```
nmcli radio wifi off
nmcli radio wifi on
```

Comment: It's not that I can't change the state of my card - it's that I want to write a script that can detect its state, change it and then bind that to a key

Answer (score 1):

With big thanks to @GAD3R

Though your script didn't work for me, I modified it slightly so that it did.

My machine wasn't able to read anything from `/sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier`, so instead I used `grep` to read from `ip a` and determine from there whether or not the state should be changed to 'up' or 'down'.

In addition to this; I also used `zenity` to display an on-screen notification of the changes I'd made. The script ended up looking like this;

```
#!/bin/bash


if
ip a | grep -q "wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>";

then
ip link set wlan0 up
zenity --notification --text="Wireless state changed to UP"

else
ip link set wlan0 down
zenity --notification --text="Wireless state changed to DOWN"

fi
```

I then used keyboard shortcuts to run this command upon pressing the hotkey.

Thanks again for any help.

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Check the stat of the wifi interface from `/sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier` , e,g:

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -q 0 /sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier ; then  
ip link set wlan0 up
else
ip link set wlan0 down
fi
```